# On XF Prims how do I pass the Master Page Viewmodel to the MasterDetailPage's ViewModel so that I can swap out the details page

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

My Master page is defined in a separate ContentPage with it's own ViewModel which handles commands for navigating and swapping out the detail page, but it's not working; navigating to a Detail Page from the Master Page VM causes the Master page to disappear. As I understanding you need to navigate from the MasterDetailPage VM. Is there any way to pass the Master Page's VM to the MasterDetailPage VM, or should I be doing something else?

```
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             x:Class="NGT.Views.MyMasterDetailPage"
             xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
             xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:NGT.Views"
             MasterBehavior="Split">

    <MasterDetailPage.Master>
        <pages:MyMenuPage/>
    </MasterDetailPage.Master>

</MasterDetailPage>
```

and in the Master's Page ViewModel (not the MasterDetailPage ViewModel):

```
    public class MyMenuPageViewModel : ChildBaseViewModel, INavigationAware
    {

           public MyMenuPageViewModel (INavigationService navigationService)
           {
                this.navigationService = navigationService;
                this.ChangeDetailPage = new DelegateCommand(this.OpenDetailPage)
           }

    public async void OpenDetailPage()
    {
        await this.NavigationService.NavigateAsync("FAQPage", animated: false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For now I have created an event for every time I want to swap out my detail page and invoke the event from MyMenuPageVM like so `OnPageChanges?.Invoke("Page1");` I then subscribe to the event on my MasterDetailPage VM to handle swapping out the detail page.

On MyMenuPageVM (Master Page):

```
public delegate void MyEventHandler(string page);
public static event MyEventHandler OnPageChanges;
```

Subscribe to event on MasterDetailPageVM and handle.

```
public void OnNavigatedTo(INavigationParameters parameters)
{
   MyMenuPageViewModel.OnPageChanges += this.ChangePage;
}

public async void ChangePage(string page)
{
    switch (page)
    {
        case "Page1":
            await this.navigationService.NavigateAsync("Page1");
            break;
        case "Page2":
            await this.navigationService.NavigateAsync("Page2");
            break;
    }
}
```

Not sure this is the right thing, but it works. :)